# Randomizing procedural cycles true displacement across particle system objects

Tags: materials

I am trying to use an particle system in Blender to create a field of objects (in this case bumpy rocks) with a procedural texture material on each object where each object has a randomized bumpy pattern (using cycles "true" displacement).

Based on feedback from below and elsewhere, I was able to get the Random output from the **Object Info** node to modify the way a procedural texture is mapped to a emitted object (which is extremely helpful).  See below to see layout:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the procedural texture pattern appears different for each ball, which is awesome.  However, if the exact same setup is used for displacement, the patterns are identical on each ball (in other words it doesn't work).

[image]

Some feedback I've gotten would indicate that what I'm trying to do is impossible in Blender, but I am definitely all ears for workarounds (or better looking forward to hearing what I did wrong here that would make this work if rectified).

Here is a link to download the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GkfZMhIYJId7pX0k0A8BxKn2HUa8WY_m/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

> ORIGINAL POST: I am trying to use an emitter to create a field of
>   objects (in this case bumpy rocks) with a procedural texture where
>   each object has a randomized bumpy pattern.   Ideally what I would
>   like to do is utilize the "Random" node output from the **Object
>   Info** node to manipulate the generated UV map in the **Mapping** node
>   in terms of "location".    So this randomized value per emitted object
>   could be utilized to make the object intersect with the procedural
>   texture at different locations (so to speak).  This would make all the
>   rocks unique in appearance. I do not want to use world space
>   coordinates as that would mean the objects could not move without
>   changing appearance. I am not a pro at python or drivers, but I would
>   prefer a driver-based solution if given the option.  At this point
>   however, any adequate solution would do. Thanks in advance for the
>   help!!!

Comment: You don't need scripting to achieve this. It can easily be done by connecting the *Random* value to the mix factor of a *Color Mix* node. Then instead of colors just plug two different *Vector Mapping* nodes with different rotation or position

Comment: This answer has been very helpful and it appears to be working when I feed the results into a diffuse color node (and I bet it would also work if I input it into a normal map node situation).  HOWEVER, I'm noticing that it does not show any variation when I plug the results into a displacement node with true displacement on.  Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: How are you using displacement? Cycles micro displacement, or modifier based one?

Comment: Cycles micro displacement.  It's very curious.  I have a procedural height map with the random elements in there.  When I input it into a color in a shader, I can see variations in each emitted object.  However, when I plug the same procedural grayscale map into the displacement node I get true displacement but the bumps are the same for each object.

Comment: Not sure how you are setting it up, but it us working fine right here

Comment: Hey @DuarteFarrajotaRamos if you have figured out a way to make this work with true displacement, I would be amazed and overjoyed if that were possible! I have put the updated details in the post above along with the project file.  LMK if you have any thoughts/ feedback.

Comment: The issue seems to be caused by the particle system. Making duplicates real seems to randomize displacement too. Expect severe slowed performance and heavy rendering process

Comment: Yes it does seem that both particle systems and dupliverts have the same problem.  Another solution is to have a particle system referring to a group of objects.  At least that helps a little and isn't as slow.